# Solid of revolution answer verification

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

The question is:

Does the integral $ \int _0^2 \pi(2^2-(2-y)^2)dy$ represent the volume of hemisphere or a cone. Give the radius of the hemisphere or radius and height of the cone.

The solution given to me:

This integral represents the volume of a cone with radius 2 and height 2. However, I don’t see how they got this answer.

My solution:

This integral represents $2/3$ of the volume of a right cylinder with radius 2 and height 2. I even confirmed this by evaluating the given integral as is and it equals $2/3$ the volume of a right cylinder with radius 2 and height 2. So it’s a right cylinder with a cone removed from it.

Any help with this would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Your idea is correct, however you're evaluating the integral as if it was in terms of $x$ so that's why your shape isn't the way that it's described in the solution given to you. Look at the variables of integration and notice that it's an integral in terms of $y$.

Comment: Can you clarify which part of my idea is correct? I’m just a bit confused on what you meant. @IgnacioRojas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

[image]

The full cylinder has diameter 4 and height 2;

Between $ x_1 =2,  x_2=2-y $ the volume is obtained by rotating about $y$- axis. It is the outer red shaded volume got after removing cone from cylinder. (Has double the volume of cone).

$$V= \int(\pi x_1^2-\pi x_2^2) dy$$

Comment: Yes, this is the idea I had and the answer I wrote. But surely the red region does not represent the volume of a cone with radius 2 and height 2 as the solution given to me says.

Comment: It is not a cone but what is left after removing the cone!

Comment: Okay, that is what I thought but the answer provided really confused me. Thank you very much for clarifying that for me!

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: So then the question as stated doesn’t make sense as the region is not a cone nor a hemisphere.

Comment: Somewhat misleading.